# Auto Acknowledgement for Client replies to Outbound Mail in Email to Case

Tags: email2case

I want to setup Auto Acknowledgement when client replies on outbound email sent from email to case. So when customer send any enquiry or issue, a case will be created and system will send an outbound mail. Suppose customer send reply to this mail, system should send an acknowledgement mail.

Can anyone help me with rule criteria ?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is quite simple. Please go to Setup and in the Quickfind box enter "Case Auto-Response Rule." There you can create an acknowledgement mail for email2case. I gave you the hint what to do so I hope now you can just figure the rest of it on your own.

Give an up-vote to this answer if it helped. :-)